# how to combine two UITableView in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I written two programs (each in separate file) in objective c

Now I want to combine this two programs in one program

each program contains UITableView

*when i combine two program in one program, it shows duplicate declaration of tableview    because combined program contains two tableView what should i do  ??*

or

*is there any other way so that i can put one tableview in one method and another tableview in  another method and i will call that two method ?*

Comment: You need to give more detail. Would one table work, populated via two alternate methods? Or do you want distinct tables? Would one grouped table work?

Comment: i want two tableview should fit in one program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Grouped Table view i.e. 2 sections for one tableView -

[image]

[This is a good tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) on customising a grouped UITableView, although it does assume that you are proficient with an image editor to create the various custom images.